# Why would two bluetooth keyboards have different performance?

Tags: bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

Why would two bluetooth keyboards have different performances?

The two keyboards are:

- [Motorola retail bluetoth tablet keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004L9MBH6)
- [Drevo Calibur 71 bluetooth mechanical keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H6DWV8M)

The former (older) performs better than the latter. The latter lags.

Comment: Are you talking about a difference in specs or actual observed performance?  Can you be more specific about the performance and the lag?  How much difference?  Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: About the observed performance. The Motorola doesn't slow down when typing while the Drevo does. The characters are not printed on the screen as fast as the Motorola & the lag causes some some characters to print before previous ones. I expect the newer keyboard to have at least the same performance if not better.

Comment: The performance should be transparent.  If you're getting those kinds of problems, it isn't a normal "performance" difference, it's a hardware or software defect.  Are you using a generic driver or one supplied for the keyboard?  Have you tried the problem keyboard on another computer?

Comment: I am using both keyboards with my laptop's internal bluetooth. Neither comes with a dongle. And other users are having the same problem as per amazon.

Comment: If other people are reporting the same faulty performance, it sounds like the keyboard is a crappy product.  You can't fix that, except by buying a different keyboard.

Comment: It's only in bluetooth that it's not performing well. When usb is connected it performs normally.

Comment: If the other keyboard works fine with the same Bluetooth connection, that suggests a problem with the Bluetooth in the bad keyboard.  And if other people report the same problems, it sounds like a bad design or defective product.  If not everybody has the problem, that suggests poor manufacturing quality/cheap components.  Still, there's nothing you can do to fix that.  Use it connected via USB, or replace it.  It it's still under warranty, you're covered.